# LSTM model is giving an ValueError while predicting based on X_test data

Tags: python, lstm, valueerror

Hi need a help to solve value erorr wile running LSTM. It seems everything works fine on training data but prediction generates less then expected dimensions
my x_train data shape is (846, 30, 3), my y_train data shape is (846,) my x_test 363, 30, 3), my y_test (363) while yhat = modell.predict(test_X) generates (363, 100)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWq0J.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last dense layer outputs 100 values because you specified so. The output is coherent with your model you give 363 samples and it predicts 363 labels with dimension `100`.

If you only need one value just change the number of neurons in your last Dense layer to 1